# Issues with repeatedly executing .pyc script

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to make an script that will every second read string from a file, and execute it.

executer.pyc:

```
import os, time
f = open("/root/codename/execute","a")
f.write("")
f.close()
cmd=open('/root/codename/execute', 'r').read()
if not cmd=="":
    os.system(cmd)
    os.system("rm /root/codename/execute")
time.sleep(1)
os.system("python executer.pyc")
```

Problem is, that it constantly f's up whole ps -aux and other similiar commands.
How can i make, that it will kill itself and then launch itself again? My idea, is a parent script that will launch executer.pyc everytime that script closes itself. But how can i make it, that it will not have effect like executer.pyc? I know this whole system how it works is kinda bad, but i just need it this way (reading from file "execute"). Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just run it in the background?

Comment: Why are you executing the `.pyc` file?

Comment: Because i want to make it run every second

Comment: How will running it in background solve it? How can i make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
os.system("python executer.pyc")
```

you can use [execfile()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile)

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier to let this script run continuously. Look at [How to use a timer to run forever?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2702890/210526) This will show you how you can repeatedly execute the same command.