# Calling method after every interval using Python Timer

Tags: python

I am trying to call one method after every 5 seconds. But, it seems it is getting called only once and program stops to execute.
Here is my code which I am trying:

```
class MyClass(object):
def getData(self):
    print "I am not able to call after every interval"
def main():
    m = MyClass()
    m.getData()

Timer(2.0, main).start()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make this timer run forever?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702890/how-can-i-make-this-timer-run-forever)

Comment: please fix the indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def getData(self):
        print "I am not able to call after every interval"

def main():
    while "foo" != "bar":
        m = MyClass()
        Timer(2.0, m.getData()).start()

main()
```